# IE9 Weird behaviour when animating SVG

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I am animating svg paths using strokeDashoffset and strokeDasharray method in ff and chrome it works and looks fine only in IE i get this weird effect.

Online example - http://www.vicsmash.com/experiments/svganim/

I tested with inline svg and getElementsByTagNameNS object embed no matter what method I use IE renders it the same - It also applies to setInterval and Requestanimframe animation - absolutely no difference.

Image url - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD0EG.png

Answer (score 1):

If IE doesn't redraw something, remember you can manually force the SVG to be redrawn using `forceRedraw` function. I think the problem here lies with the plugin you're using, but unfortunately I can't be sure.

You can fix the issue by creating an intervalled function that redraws the SVG, during the duration of animation (hopefully the plugin allows for onStart / onEnd events to target setting and clearing of the interval), but for the purpose of "does it even work", here's the fiddle using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/eithe/qseGX/

(I needed jQuery only for document.ready event and traversing of nodes, you can safely remove it in your code)

Comment: I added the force redraw on SVGSVGElenment per frame and it still does the same stuff. I dont think that's the library issue as I tried the same with requestanimframe and intervals just in pure js it doesn't seem to work. Even the jsfiddle example seem to be breaking.

Comment: Ok redraw essentially was the answer but it had to be done on the body - so in my onUpdate that fires every frame i added:

var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
document.body.appendChild(n);
document.body.removeChild(n);

This seems to fix the IE Issue - I will upload the example in a second so it will be available for the future :)